# HTML & Python: HTML webpage calling a python program to download/produce a .csv file

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to create a website to act as a control for my program to produce a .csv file.
Here is the link to my github repository: https://github.com/tamuel97/Income-energy

Python code:

```
    def CastleHill():
      device_ = 'DD64108179557'
      starting_time = StartTime(device_)
      file_name = choose_file_name(device_)
      iterations = numiterations(starting_time, granularity)
      writeHeaders(file_name)

  for x in range(iterations):

    response = data(device_,starting_time)
    writecsv(response, file_name)
    starting_time = nextweek(starting_time, granularity)
```

HTML code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="CastleHill()">Castle Hill</button>
```

Comment: You can't run it directly - web browser can't run Python code. You have to send HTTP request to server which will run it. SO better learn Python web framework like `Flask`, `Django`, `Bottle`.